# If cell is N/A, keep if N/A and not matched to Yes or NO

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using this formula to match values between two sheets.

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(G3,'sheet'!$G$3:$J$900000,0))), "Yes", "No")
```

both sheets have `N/A` in specific columns and as a result the formula return a `YES`.

I want to add a clause to indicate that if `G` cells have `N/A` results should be `N/A`, not `Yes`

i am lost
wonder if an `Xlookup` might be a better route.
Maybe an `AND`
I read about `IF(ISNA()` but not sure how to add to my formula

Comment: `900000` are you sure about this many number of rows? Better would be using `VBA` instead of formulas

Comment: Can you explain it with data?

Comment: The formula i have been using =IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(G3,'sheet'!$G$3:$J$300000,0))), "Yes", "No")    is working perfectly, matching with Yes or No. But I have some N/A values so teh formula return Yes (because it found a N/A on the other sheet. I want to keep the same  Yes and NO, just add an exception, that when the cell has N/A, do not enter Yes or No, but keep it N/A

Comment: If you have `N/A` in both the sheets, then why dont use the `IF()` logic to see if its an `N/A` to return `N/A` and then do the rest. If I am not wrong then this should work : `=IF(ISNA(G3),NA(),IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(G3,'sheet'!$G$3:$J$300000,0))), "Yes", "No"))`

Comment: thanks Mayukh. It did return a Yes though :(  and it should have been NA

Comment: As asked above by @P.b Sir, please post some data to explain enough

Comment: not sure what kind of data. do you mean an excel sheet? 
 I have a column Key in two sheets, from 2 separate data sets and i want to see if they both match. in Columns Key, most of the ddata will be a perticular name that I want my formula to match excatly, but in a few cases I have N/A in column Key

Comment: Please see **[How to create a Minimal, Complete, & Verifiable eg.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)** & read **[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/.../how-much-research...)** & don't forget to read **[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/.../why-is-can-someone...)** . Also check out the **[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)**

Comment: Test this one: `=IF(ISERROR(A2),NA(),IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(G3,'sheet'!$G$3:$J$300000,0))), "Yes", "No"))`